# Selenium Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: not working on linux server

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can’t understand why I can’t find the class.
This code works fine on win10.
Why does this not work on linux (centos7)?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

global chrome_driver
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

def my_auth():
    driver = chrome_driver
    driver.maximize_window()
    my_url = 'https://login:pass@site.com'
    driver.get(my_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('ladda-label').click()
```

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ladda-label"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=81.0.4044.138)

I will be glad to any version why this did not work on linux. How can I check that I got to the site?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working in headless mode, it may be helpful to add window-size to your options. For example:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
```